# CATIA File Open optimization

Tags: catia

A few thousand IGES files take a considerable amount of time to open / import into CATIA. I would like to understand which are the ways to optimize this use-case.

CATIA V5 has the option to import various file formats, like IGS, through File -> Open.
When importing say, one IGS file, a dialog like "Converting Data..." is shown.

[Converting data snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHOan.png)

When importing a few thousands or more from such files, the data conversion step on a recent Intel PC with enough RAM seems to take a significant amount of time.

I would like to understand more about this conversion in order to optimize the use-case when importing multiple files takes "longer than usual".

Does someone maybe know into which file format is CATIA converting an IGS (or other file format) file internally during a File -> Open operation? Is it a CATIA internal or a standard file-format which may be used to avoid this data conversion during the CATIA File import operation?

Could this CATIA "data conversion" step be parallelized (either partly or fully) and / or cached, for example on CPUs with multiple cores, to reduce the overall import time?
Would a custom CATIA plugin be useful to obtain a considerable (at least 2x) improvement?

What other ways to optimize such use-cases are you aware of?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the batch utility from tools (which is working in background) if you have the necessary license. Or you can create a macro to open the files in batch mode, convert them to CATIA files, save where you want and close. You can find related articles here https://v5vb.wordpress.com/